# Storing in javascript array vs. (LocalStorage and IndexDB)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How is storing values directly in Javascript arrays is different than from storing them in come client side alternative like LocalStorage or IndexDB.

Where the values get stored in either cases. And what are limits.

My use case is: to store very fast data (float values) coming from server somewhere and then read it from that middle source to render the points on a real time plot/graph. Does the frequency also makes a difference to the choice ?

Any sample code snippet will be of great use.

Comment: You will most certainly be optimizing the rendering of data and possibly the client-side processing. That is your main bottlenecks, not the storage itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obvious differences between localStorage and arrays are :

- you can only store strings (no objects)
- it's persisted so that you'll get your values back next time
- as it writes on disk it's a heavier operation
- the available space is limited to avoid cluttering the user's disk (*"User agents should limit the total amount of space allowed for storage areas.[...] A mostly arbitrary limit of five megabytes per origin is recommended"*)

**[W3.org reference on localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)**

You read and write in localStorage like this :

```
var foo = localStorage["bar"];
// ...
localStorage["bar"] = foo;
```

(example taken from the great introductory site http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

**If you're only using your data for the current session, don't use localStorage**. Use standard arrays (they're fine and fast) or [Float32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Float32Array).

Comment: Why not use `getItem()` and `setItem()` methods instead?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. But my doubt goes unresolved. So, I have to store few thousand float values every second. And I want to store these for 2 minutes and discard values which are older than that. So, what is the right way ? Any harm in plainly storing them in a javascript array ? so it will be like 500kbps of data => 50-60 mb for 2 minutes.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for comment. Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @David because the brace notation is cleaner and prettier... but you may if you want use getItem and setItem.

Comment: @user969107 There is no point in using localStorage to store data only for current session.

Comment: ok thanks. That helps. But then storing 500kbs of float values for 2 mins leads to 60 mb of data. Storing that much in javascript array is all right ? or can lead to any issues.

Comment: @dystroy Standard methods wins over "cleaner and prettier" in my book. F.ex, The code you posted will get undefined instead of null for non-set values.

Comment: @user969107 500,000 float shouldn't take 60 Mb. And it won't take much more than 2 Mb if you use a Float32Array. Avoid using strings or localStorage for your floats.

Comment: Actually there are 3000 float values every 20milliseconds. So,  3000*50 = 150,000 per second and 150,000 * 120 in 2 minutes

Comment: I've yet made web app with so many floats (scientific applications), it works, but you'll have to do a lot of work in optimization (profiling cpu and memory, testing alternatives).

Comment: I'm pretty sure IndexedDB is alive and well. I think you're confusing it with the sqlite-based WebSQLDB (which was deprecated in 2010).

Comment: @KrisJenkins You're right. But I never saw anything built around IndexedDB, I don't know if it's going to be used.